# Encouraging questioners to answer their own self-study questions

Tags: discussion, tags, policy

I just had a thought: we should encourage askers of [self-study] questions to write up (and accept) the answers the answers that they end up with.

The question here is: is that a good idea?

If we accept it, we could 
(a) as individuals do so, and 
(b) modify the description of the self-study tag to indicate this policy.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to make this a *rule*; but it may be appropriate sometimes. I'd say we could have this as a helpful suggestion, but leave it to the discretion of the user who is interacting w/ the OP.

Comment: On the TeX-LaTex board, in questions that get a lot of comments, there is often a summary written up by the original poster.

Comment: I'm all for such encouragement, especially when the OP makes it clear they have solved their problem. I've encouraged askers to post their solutions after receiving the guidance they were seeking before (and made some further suggestions if the solutions had obvious problems). I think this has advantages both for the site overall, as well as the OP. But I don't think it needs to be an official policy. I wouldn't mind there being something of a cultural shift toward encouraging OPs to post summaries of many comments that collectively cover much or all of the answer, as Peter Flom notes on TeXSE

Comment: People not following through on self-study is one thing; people not seeing an occasion for self-study is another, and a bigger concern for me. Often answers and comments reveal gaps in the questioners' knowledge; when the questioners do not follow up with study, further engagement can be unpleasant.